# gulp, webpack and webpack.DefinePlugin compile time configuration not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

I am attempting to use webpack, combined with gulp,  to perform token substitution  on the source js files so that code can be tailored to a specific deployment environment . However, I am not able to perform  the desired transform. I expect **ENVIRONMENT** to be replaced with **Production**, but no such transformation occurs.

**test.js**

```
 console.log(ENVIRONMENT );
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require("gulp-webpack");

gulp.task('default', ['webpack'], function() { });

gulp.task('webpack', function () {

  return gulp
    .src("test.js")
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./results"));
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
 output: {
        filename: "out.js"
 },  
  plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
ENVIRONMENT:JSON.stringify("Production")
     }) 
   ]
};
```

This creates a file in results/out.js, but **Production** is not injected.